# UIImagePicker not allowed edit image

Tags: ios, merge, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I'am try to use UIImagePicker with edit image, the code working good, but don't allowed editing, here my code:

On `myFile.h`

```
@interface MyCameraPickerController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate> {

    UIImageView * imageView;
    UIButton * choosePhotoBtn;
    UIButton * takePhotoBtn;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView * imageView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton * choosePhotoBtn;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton * takePhotoBtn;

-(IBAction) getPhoto:(id) sender;
```

Now on `myFile.m` calling all functions:

```
@synthesize imageView,choosePhotoBtn, takePhotoBtn;

-(IBAction) getPhoto:(id) sender {

    UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    picker.delegate = self;

    if((UIButton *) sender == choosePhotoBtn) {

        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;

    } else {

        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    }

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

    imageView.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

After this working i merged two image and working very well here the code if anyone can help ;) :

```
- (IBAction)onSavePhoto:(id)sender{

    UIImage *bottomImage = self.imageView.image;//[UIImage imageNamed:@"bottom.png"]; //background image
    UIImage *image       = [UIImage imageNamed:@"overLay.png"]; //foreground image

    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(640, 640);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );

    // Use existing opacity as is
    [bottomImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];

    // Apply supplied opacity if applicable
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newImage, nil, nil, nil);
}
```

I see my image, i can teake a Photo, but i can't editing this, anyone have idea? thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by editing? That UIImagePickerController allows you to move and scale?

Comment: Yes, i will to do a possibility for scaling and cropping the image

Comment: Then, you can try `picker.allowsEditing=true'

Comment: Very very good!!! if you want post the answer i vote you with correct answer thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is the built-in `UIImagePickerController` to allow editing of the selected image, just establish the `allowsEditing` property:

```
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
```

And later you can retrieve it like this:

```
[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
```